# I got a 500 error when I use guzzle but with curl I dont get one

Tags: request, guzzle, openhab

I have an Openhab system on a PI and a REST API and I want to display information on a TV-Screen.

I have tried to do it with a curl and it worked. So now I want to do the same  with Guzzle.
First I only installed composer and guzzle in the Project directory on my PC, Then I also installed them on the PI. Neither approach worked as I got a 500 error on both attempts.

```
function getCurrentTemp() {
    echo "test1";
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'base_uri'=>'http://fernseher/'
    ]);

    echo "test2";
    $return = $client->request('GET','http://openhab.clubdrei.com/rest/items/ThermostateTemp/state', ['auth' => ['User','Password']]);
    echo $return;
}
```

I think the creating Client break up the script

I need your help,
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`500` basically means that there is a server error. Please attach the cURL command that is successful (as you mentioned in the question's title).

I also modified your code a bit, to be sure that you are are working with the body content of the response (`->getBody()->getContents()` part):

```
function getCurrentTemp()
{
    // You don't need 'base_uri' here, because you use absolute URL below
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $response = $client->request(
        'GET',
        'http://openhab.clubdrei.com/rest/items/ThermostateTemp/state',
        ['auth' => ['User','Password']]
    );

    return $response->getBody()->getContents();
}
```